# Isi B.Math Fibonacci problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $\dbinom{n}{k}$ denote the binomial coefficient $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ , and $F_m$ be the $m^{th}$ Fibonacci number given by $F_1=F_2=1$ and $F_{m+2}=F_m+F_{m+1}$ for all $m\geq 1$. Show that

$\sum \dbinom{n}{k}=F_{m+1}$ for all $m\geq 1$ .
Here the above sum is over all pairs of integers $n\geq k\geq 0$ with $n+k=m$

Okay, I got an induction proof for this problem. but I was wondering if this sum can be done in any other way.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s well known that $F_{m+1}$ is the number of ways to write $m$ as an ordered sum of $1$s and $2$s. E.g., $4$ can be so written in $F_5=5$ ways:

$$\begin{align*}
4&=1+1+1+1\\
&=2+1+1\\
&=1+2+1\\
&=1+1+2\\
&=2+2
\end{align*}$$

How many such representations of $m$ have exactly $k$ $2$s? Such a representation must have $m-2k$ $1$s, so it has $m-k$ terms, and there are

$$\binom{m-k}k=\binom{n}k$$

ways to choose which $k$ terms are $2$s. Summing over $k$ now yields the desired result.